# A correct implementation of the methods that deal with a pointer to an interface

Tags: c++, com, vb6

I have a COM object that is implemented in C++. I am using this object from a VB6 application.

The question is how to implement a methods that get and return a pointer to an interface.
Here is the sample of an IDL:

```
[...]
interface ICOMCvDC : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT GetPen([retval][out] ICOMCvPen** ppPen);
    HRESULT SetPen([in] ICOMCvPen* pPen);
};
```

And below is the skeleton of the component class object:

```
class COMCvDC : public ICOMCvDC
{
public:
    ...
    STDMETHODDECL GetPen(
        /* [retval][out] */ ICOMCvPen** ppPen);
    STDMETHODDECL SetPen(
        /* [in] */ ICOMCvPen* pPen);
    ...

protected:
    ICOMCvPen* m_pen;
};

...

STDMETHODIMP COMCvDC::GetPen(
    /* [retval][out] */ ICOMCvPen** ppPen)
{
    *ppPen = m_pen;
    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP COMCvDC::SetPen(
    /* [in] */ ICOMCvPen* pPen)
{
    m_pen = pPen;
    return S_OK;
}
```

I am a beginner in COM, so I am unsure if I do it the right way. I feel like I need to use `QueryInterface` method on some of the interface pointers. Also it is interesting to know what VB6 is doing when it interprets the code like:

```
Dim pen1 As ICOMCvPen
Set pen1 = dc1.GetPen()
```

Does it call the `AddRef` method on the interface pointer returned by `GetPen` method?

### Update 1

I have implemented two test objects (COMCvTest and COMCvTestFactory) that just log all the methods being called. Then I executed the following VB6 code:

```
Dim test1 As ICOMCvTest
Set test1 = New COMCvTest
Debug.Print "Ref: " & test1.GetReferenceCounter
Set test1 = Nothing
```

Below is the log of the life cycle of these objects:

```
COMCvTestFactory::COMCvTestFactory(); m_cRef = 1
COMCvTestFactory::QueryInterface() --- begin ---
    IID is {00000001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
    IID is IID_IClassFactory
    COMCvTestFactory::AddRef(); m_cRef = 2 (was 1)
COMCvTestFactory::QueryInterface() ---- end ----
COMCvTestFactory::Release(); m_cRef = 1 (was 2)
COMCvTestFactory::CreateInstance() --- begin ---
    COMCvTest::COMCvTest(); m_cRef = 1
    COMCvTest::QueryInterface() --- begin ---
        IID is {00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
        IID is IID_IUnknown
        COMCvTest::AddRef(); m_cRef = 2 (was 1)
    COMCvTest::QueryInterface() ---- end ----
    COMCvTest::Release(); m_cRef = 1 (was 2)
COMCvTestFactory::CreateInstance() ---- end ----
COMCvTest::AddRef(); m_cRef = 2 (was 1)
COMCvTest::Release(); m_cRef = 1 (was 2)
COMCvTestFactory::Release(); m_cRef = 0 (was 1); deleting object
COMCvTestFactory::~COMCvTestFactory()
COMCvTest::QueryInterface() --- begin ---
    IID is {00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
    IID is IID_IUnknown
    COMCvTest::AddRef(); m_cRef = 2 (was 1)
COMCvTest::QueryInterface() ---- end ----
COMCvTest::QueryInterface() --- begin ---
    IID is {9F660698-1950-4DE8-BB5F-C8D2D61F7367}
    IID is IID_ICOMCvTest
    COMCvTest::AddRef(); m_cRef = 3 (was 2)
COMCvTest::QueryInterface() ---- end ----
COMCvTest::QueryInterface() --- begin ---
    IID is {7FD52380-4E07-101B-AE2D-08002B2EC713}
    IID is IID_IPersistStreamInit
COMCvTest::QueryInterface() --- begin ---
    IID is {37D84F60-42CB-11CE-8135-00AA004BB851}
    IID is IID_IPersistPropertyBag
COMCvTest::Release(); m_cRef = 2 (was 3)
COMCvTest::Release(); m_cRef = 1 (was 2)
COMCvTest::GetReferenceCounter; m_cRef = 1
COMCvTest::Release(); m_cRef = 0 (was 1); deleting object
COMCvTest::~COMCvTest()
```

It seems like VB6 is trying to query `IPersistStreamInit` and `IPersistPropertyBag` interfaces from the COM object. Why? Also I don't understand why there is a query of `IUnknown` interface before query of `ICOMCvTest` interface pointer?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special with interface pointer management, except one thing: you have to take care of AddRef/Release calls. This is why it is strongly recommended to use smart pointer wrapper that do auto-management (C++ pseudo-code):

```
CComPtr<ICOMCvPen> m_pen;

HRESULT Get(IPen** ppPen) { ... *ppPen = CComPtr<ICOMCvPen>(m_pen).Detach();  ... }
HRESULT Set(IPen* pPen) { ... m_pen = pPen;  ... }
```

And that's it! If you don't use CComPtr, you have to do "if(!x) x->Release()" stuff all the way and it's so easy to make a mistake.

### Re: Update 1

- `IUnknown` might be queried first if `IID_IUnknown` was the argument in VB6's CoCreateInstance; then it `QueryInterface`'d the interface of interest.
- a query for `IPersistStreamInit` and `IPersistPropertyBag` is perhaps a part of standard object initialization with VB6 runtime; should this object be loaded with the form, it could be initialized from persistent data.

Also note that it's typical to pre-query certain interfaces off the object right during initialization so that they are ready when they needed later, esp. if they are to be reused.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, QueryInterface() makes it a clean one-liner that takes advantage of any error handling built-in QI and takes care of the reference count you have to add:

```
STDMETHODIMP COMCvDC::GetPen(ICOMCvPen** ppPen)
{
    if (m_pen) return m_pen->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ICOMCvPen), (void**)ppPen);
    else {
        *ppPen = 0;
        return E_FAIL;
    }
}

STDMETHODIMP COMCvDC::SetPen(ICOMCvPen* pPen)
{
    if (m_pen) m_pen->Release();
    m_pen = pPen;
    return S_OK;
}
```

Don't forget to initialize m_pen to NULL in the constructor and release it in the destructor.  Or use a smart pointer.